# If $I \subset J$ and $J \cap K = JK$, then is it true that $I \cap K = IK$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The question is as the title says: If $I \subset J$ and $J \cap K = JK$, then is it true that $I \cap K = IK$? If it is not true, then are there assumptions on $R$ that can make it true?

For instance, the statement holds if $J \subset k[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$, $K \subset k[y_1 , \dots , y_m]$ (and the intersection is viewed in the larger polynomial ring $k[x_1 , \dots , x_n, y_1 , \dots , y_m]$). Likewise, in the case that $R$ is regular/local, this should be equivalent to asking that $\textrm{Tor}_1^R (J/I , R/K) = 0$ (this uses rigidity of Tor).

Any ideas (or counterexamples) would be very enlightening to me.

Comment: For principal ideals if is $\, j\mid i,\ (j,k) = (1) \Rightarrow\, (i,k) = (1),\,$ true iff $\,(j/i,k)= 1\ \ $

Comment: since $\,(i,k) = ((i/j)j,k) = (i/j,k)\,$ by $\,(j,k)=1\,$ and Euclid. So you'll need to work past that obstruction to get a correct generalization. But maybe you mistyped...

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=k[x]$, $K=(x)$ and $I=(x)\subseteq J=(1)$.

Clearly, $J\cap K=K=JK$. However, $I\cap K=(x)\ne IK=(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could just consider some case like $I\subsetneq K\subsetneq J=R$.

For example, take $R=\Bbb Z[x]$, $I=(2x)$, $K=(x)$, $J=(1)$ so $I\subsetneq K\subsetneq J=R$.

Then $J\cap K=K=(x)=JK$, but $I\cap K=I=(2x)$, so $2x\in I\cap K$, while $2x\notin IK$ .

Comment: Does this answer your question?